# How to enable gzip support when using Quarkus rest client reactive?

Tags: java, kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I'm using `io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client-reactive:2.10.3.Final` to make a request like this:

```kotlin
@RegisterRestClient
interface QweatherRestClient {

    @GET
    @Path(value = "/warning/now")
    fun getWarningNow(
        @QueryParam(value = "key") key: String,
        @QueryParam(value = "location") location: String
    ): GetWarningNowResponse

}
```

The server returns a response with gzip encoding, which makes jackson throw an exception:

> Request failed: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 31)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens

I can see gzip file magic number (1f 8b) if use ByteArray as the return type, instead of an object in the sample code.

I found a question [How to receive a GZIP response with RESTClient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68905302) maybe related. `io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client` has `GZIPDecodingInterceptor` while the reactive one doesn't have this. Are there any alternative ways to receive responses with gzip encoding using the reactive rest client?

Comment: I don't think we have support for that yet. Mind opening a feature request on GitHub?

Comment: @geoand Thanks! Here is the request: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/26981